# Entity Framework cache vs Context.Items

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I've recently started using EF4.3.

I have some data that I get for each request - page configuration data being an example. I get this data from the database.

Until recently I've been storing this in `Context.items` as it allows me to persist this data throughout the request.

The question I have is, now that i'm using EF with tracking (i use it on a per request basis), in theory the page config should be cached when it is first fetched, so any subsequent calls for it should be less expensive although maybe not comparable to `context.items`.

Is this the case or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you query the data using the `ObjectSet/DbSet` it will always hit the database even though you have queried the same data before. You have to use a different querying technique to get the data from cached items.

If you are using the `DbContext/DbSet` API you can query the cache using.

```
var items = dbContext.Products.Local.Where(/**/);
```

In the case of `ObjectContext`

```
var items = objectContext.ObjectStateManager
        .GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Unchanged | EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified)
        .Where(e => e.Entity is Product)....;
```